# XML against XSD from file with MinOccurance using XDocument

Tags: xml, xsd, linq-to-xml

i use some xsdMarkup

```
   string xsdMarkup =
        @"<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
    <xs:schema attributeFormDefault='unqualified' elementFormDefault='qualified' xmlns:xs='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema'>
      <xs:element name='catalog'>
        <xs:complexType>
          <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element maxOccurs='unbounded' name='book'>
              <xs:complexType>
                <xs:sequence>
                  <xs:element name='authors'>
                    <xs:complexType>
                      <xs:sequence>
                        <xs:element maxOccurs='unbounded' name='author' type='xs:string' />
                      </xs:sequence>
                    </xs:complexType>
                  </xs:element>
                  <xs:element name='title' type='xs:string' maxOccurs='1' minOccurs='1' />
                  <xs:element name='genre' type='xs:string' maxOccurs='1' minOccurs='1' />
                  <xs:element name='price' type='xs:string' maxOccurs='1' minOccurs='1'/>
                  <xs:element name='publish_date' type='xs:string' maxOccurs='1' />
                  <xs:element name='description' type='xs:string' maxOccurs='1' />
                </xs:sequence>
                <xs:attribute name='id' type='xs:unsignedByte' use='required' />
              </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
          </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
      </xs:element>
    </xs:schema>";


 XmlSchemaSet schemas = new XmlSchemaSet();
```

next method validating:

```
public string ValidateXml(XDocument doc)
    {
        string errors_text = "";
        bool errors = false;
        doc.Validate(schemas, (o, e) =>
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
            errors = true;
            errors_text += e.Message;
        });

        Label1.Content = (errors == true) ? "nie przeszło" : "przeszło";

        return errors_text;
    }
```

Opening the file and validating that file:

```
 private void OpenFile_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
             schemas.Add("", XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(xsdMarkup)));
            OpenFileDialog openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
            openFileDialog.Multiselect = false;
            openFileDialog.Filter = "XML files (*.XML)|*.XML|All files (*.*)|*.*";

            if (openFileDialog.ShowDialog() == true)
            {
               XDocument asd = XDocument.Load(openFileDialog.FileName);
               ValidateXml(asd);           
            }
```

but if my file misses title, genre, publish_date, price i do not get any error, i wonder why is that? Can you help me on that matter??

here is example .xml file that i load

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<catalog>
 <book  id="001">
  <authors>
   <author>P</author>
   <author>A</author>
  </authors>
  <title>XML Developer's Guide</title>
  <genre>Computer</genre>
  <price>44.95</price>
  <publish_date>2000-10-01</publish_date>
  <description>An in-depth look at creating applications with XML.</description>
 </book>
 <book  id="002">
  <authors>
   <author>K</author>
  </authors>
  <title>Midnight Rain</title>
  <genre>Fantasy</genre>
  <price>5.95</price>
  <publish_date>2000-12-16</publish_date>
  <description>A former architect battles corporate zombies, an evil sorceress, and her own childhood to become queen of the world.</description>
 </book>
 <book  id="003">
  <authors>
   <author></author>
  </authors>
  <title></title>
  <genre></genre>
  <price></price>
  <publish_date></publish_date>
  <description></description>
 </book>
 <book id="004">
  <authors>
   <author>asd</author>
  </authors>
  <title>asd</title>
  <genre>asdasd</genre>
  <price></price>
  <publish_date></publish_date>
  <description></description>
 </book>
</catalog>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I notice that your XML file does have tags for `title`, `genre`, and `publish_date` in every case.  It's just that some of them are empty.

All of them are strings, and the empty string is a valid string.  So (I assume) the XML parser thinks that these tags have valid values.

All your schema specifies is that the tags need to be there.  It doesn't say anything about what the strings they contain need to look like.

You will probably have to refine your schema to include further restrictions on the value (such as a minimum length, or a non-string data type for the price) if you want empty tags to be treated as errors.